# Is $g_0(u + ct)$ in d'Alembert's formula evaluated at $u(t)$ or $(u(0))$?

Tags: waves, mathematics

I'm a complete noob to [d'Alembert's general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) the one-dimensional wave equation. Very slowly, I'm starting to understand it, although this has been difficult because the usual example applications given on the internet are quite different from the unconventional application I have in mind.

One thing in particular keeps tying my brain in knots:

Given a function $g(u(t), t)$ satisfying the one dimensional wave equation

$$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t^2} - c \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial u^2} = 0
$$

And D'Alambert's solution

$$
g(u(t), t) = \frac{1}{2} (g_0(u + ct) + g_0(u - ct)) + \frac{1}{2 c} \int_{u - ct}^{u + ct} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} |_{t = 0} \: d\omega
$$

Where $g_0 = g(u(0), 0)$

At what time is the $u$ in $g_0(u + ct)$ evaluated? Is it $g_0(u(0) + ct)$ or $g_0(u(t) + ct)$? The tutorials I have seen on the internet never specify this.

In my own, home grown example, I have

$$
g_0 = g(u(0), 0) = k e^{-u(0)} + a
$$

Where $k$ and $a$ are constants.

So, is it

$$
g_0(u(0) + ct) = k e^{-u(0) - ct} + a
$$

or

$$
g_0(u(t) + ct) = k e^{-u(t) - ct} + a
$$

?

Same question for the bounds of the integral.

Considering the examples I've seen on the internet, it seems to me that $u(0) + ct$ makes more sense--we're talking about an initial position plus a displacement after time $t$. But then this would mean that the left-hand side of D'Alambert's solution (second displayed equation) has to be $g(u(0), t)$, not $g(u(t), t)$. In which case, I don't undertand why D'Alambert's solution shouldn't more properly be expressed:

$$
g(u(t), \Delta t) = \frac{1}{2} (g_0(u + c \Delta t) + g_0(u - c \Delta t)) + \frac{1}{2 c} \int_{u - c \Delta t}^{u + c \Delta t} \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} |_{t = 0} \: d\omega
$$

And I start to go insane.

Comment: But $u$ is not a function of $t$, it's just the spatial coordinate. Maybe you're confused because $u$ is often used as a name for the solution, which you've called $g$.

Comment: @Javier So $du/dt = 0$ in D'Alambert land? Pretty sure my confusion is not merely notational.

Comment: When you're solving the 2D wave equation, the solution will tell you what the wave amplitude $g$ is at a given position $u$ at a given time $t$.  In other words, $t$ and $u$ can be specified independently;  $u$ is not a function of $t$.